# Was The Imaginarium of Doctor Parnassus a Suicide Note?

Tags: analysis, ending, the-imaginarium-of-doctor-parnassus

The question which I am asking could spoil the ending of The Imaginarium of Doctor Parnassus.

I strongly, very strongly believe that this movie was the Suicide Note of Heath Ledger. So, the question is, is the movie his suicide note or am I misunderstanding what the movie's theme is about?

My understanding of the ending of the movie is as following:

> To escape the "dream" which he was in, he had to kill himself to be the last person they needed to save Parnassus's daughter, and in real life, it was a note for him to "escape" fame and reality as we know it

Comment: @all Any better ideas for the tag fitting into the 25-char limit? Maybe `imaginarium-dr-parnassus`?

Comment: Officially Heath Ledger's death was [ruled an accident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heath_Ledger#Autopsy_and_toxicology_report), so speculating about a 'suicide note' means speculating about his death being a suicide, which I feel is off-topic here.

Comment: Also, Ledger died long before the movie was actually finished (The film was around 1/3 completed at the time), I would speculate (As this entire question is completely speculative) that if he had intended it to be a suicide note, he would have finished the film first.

Comment: False premise (Heath Ledger's death was not ruled to be suicide)

Comment: The part which we forget, a lot of suicides are not announced as a suicide, but I strongly believe that it was one in this case.

Comment: @close-voters While this question *might* be grounded on the false premise of *Heath Ledger* commiting suicide (and I agree that we're not here to reason about the truth of this fact), I still don't think the question is off-topic or any more primarily opinion-based than many other good analysis questions. It is indeed quite speculative and seemingly ungrounded, but many analysis questions are (and it would be a shame to trade this one in for yet another plot-hole or ID question)...

Comment: ...But I hope someone comes up with an answer concentrating more on the actual themes of the movie than the existing one that just says *"it's practically unlikely"*. This would give the much better question about the movie's themes and their relation to suicide in general (disregarding *Heath Ledger*'s supposed one) a bit more substance.

Comment: I like this question, but it's not a good fit for _this_ site. It's ultimately based on a very opinionated idea, as opposed to anything factual, and thus can only result in heavily subjective answers. This is a question for a forum - not a Q and A site.

Comment: @AndrewMartin *"can only result in heavily subjective answers"* - Not if facts actually contradict his theory. But I see your point.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Good point actually! Should have been more careful in my wording. That wasn't in any way intended to be a sleight on your answer (which, as per usual, is rather good) :)

Answer (score 3):

While this is an interesting question, I'll have to make the killjoy here and say, **No, this is quite unlikely** (even if I don't have a hard proof either and interpretation is still a free good).

First of all, as Oliver_C points out in his comment, **it is not entirely clear *if Heath Ledger* commited suicide in the first place and [the official version is that he didn't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heath_Ledger#Autopsy_and_toxicology_report)**.

But even if he did then this suicide note connection can only be unintentional, since **he was not so much responsible for the story and making of the movie** at all, he just starred in it. And it would be extremely unlikely for him to have some weird arrangement with *Terry Gilliam* to make him some kind of "suicide note movie" for a long planned suicide. Likewise [**his death was initially a pretty severe problem for the yet unfinished movie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Imaginarium_of_Doctor_Parnassus#Effects_of_Heath_Ledger.27s_death) (before they came up with the genuine idea of replacing him with other famous actors in the dream world):

> Gilliam was presiding over concept art when he was informed by a phone
>   call that Ledger had died. His initial thought about the production
>   was: "The film's over, it's as simple as that."

So it seems pretty unlikely that *Heath Ledger* planned his suicide (if even suicide at all) such a long time in advance and managed *Terry Gilliam* to make him a personal suicide note movie.

And furthermore, he was quite different from his role in the end:

> To escape the "dream" which he was in, he had to kill himself to be
>   the last person they needed to save Parnassus's daughter

While this is true, ***Tony* (*Ledger*'s character) certainly did not *want* to sacrifice himself** but, as we learn during the movie, always had quite selfish intentions. He needed to be tricked into death by *Parnassus* (who offered him a fake pipe that didn't help him survive at the gallows). So even if by actions, ***Tony* did not commit suicide by intentions**.

So all in all I think your theory doesn't hold water and I guess you might be able to interpret something like this into any of *Heath Ledger*'s later performances if you really want.